# Django: Internet Explorer POSTs an empty form

Tags: python, django, forms, internet-explorer

I have a `ModelForm` that works perfectly for FireFox and Chrome, but for some reason, whenever anybody submits the form with IE, the server just receives the form with empty values. I've verified this by printing the submitted values in `form.is_valid()` (as you can see below).

Here is my code:

*template.html:*

```
<form id="tracking_form" action="/tracking/{{ view.person.id }}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.person }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Add Data" style="width: 190px;">
</form>
```

*forms.py:*

```
class TrackingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, active_student=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TrackingForm, self ).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        points_dict = {'class': 'weekday_points', 'min': 0, 'max': 100 }
        arrived_dict = { 'class': 'not_required' }


        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.widget.attrs['form'] = 'tracking_form'
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form_field'
            field.required = False

        self.fields['monday_points'].widget.attrs.update(points_dict)
        self.fields['tuesday_points'].widget.attrs.update(points_dict)
        self.fields['wednesday_points'].widget.attrs.update(points_dict)
        self.fields['thursday_points'].widget.attrs.update(points_dict)
        self.fields['friday_points'].widget.attrs.update(points_dict)
        self.fields['monday_arrived'].widget.attrs.update(arrived_dict)
        self.fields['tuesday_arrived'].widget.attrs.update(arrived_dict)
        self.fields['wednesday_arrived'].widget.attrs.update(arrived_dict)
        self.fields['thursday_arrived'].widget.attrs.update(arrived_dict)
        self.fields['friday_arrived'].widget.attrs.update(arrived_dict)

    def is_valid(self):
        # This is just here to print the values server receives
        for name, field in self.fields.items():

            if field.disabled:
                value = self.get_initial_for_field(field, name)
            else:
                value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
            print(name, ":", field.clean(value))

        valid = super(TrackingForm, self).is_valid()

        return valid


    class Meta:

        model = models.Tracking
        exclude = ('person',)
```

This is the log when submitting the form with FireFox:

```
2018-11-16 02:23:15 week : 3
2018-11-16 02:23:15 term : 4
2018-11-16 02:23:15 year : 2018
2018-11-16 02:23:15 b1 : fasd
2018-11-16 02:23:15 b2 : asdfsad
2018-11-16 02:23:15 monday_points : 0
2018-11-16 02:23:15 monday_attended : 1
2018-11-16 02:23:15 monday_arrived : 09:00:00
2018-11-16 02:23:15 tuesday_points : 0
2018-11-16 02:23:15 tuesday_attended : 1
2018-11-16 02:23:15 tuesday_arrived : 09:00:00
2018-11-16 02:23:15 wednesday_points : 0
2018-11-16 02:23:15 wednesday_attended : 1
2018-11-16 02:23:15 wednesday_arrived : 10:30:00
2018-11-16 02:23:15 thursday_points : 0
2018-11-16 02:23:15 thursday_attended : 1
2018-11-16 02:23:15 thursday_arrived : 09:00:00
2018-11-16 02:23:15 friday_points : 0
2018-11-16 02:23:15 friday_attended : 1
2018-11-16 02:23:15 friday_arrived : 09:00:00
```

And this is the log from submitting the same form in IE:

```
2018-11-16 02:23:41 week : 
2018-11-16 02:23:41 term : 
2018-11-16 02:23:41 year : 
2018-11-16 02:23:41 b1 : 
2018-11-16 02:23:41 b2 : 
2018-11-16 02:23:41 monday_points : None
2018-11-16 02:23:41 monday_attended : 
2018-11-16 02:23:41 monday_arrived : 
2018-11-16 02:23:41 tuesday_points : None
2018-11-16 02:23:41 tuesday_attended : 
2018-11-16 02:23:41 tuesday_arrived : 
2018-11-16 02:23:41 wednesday_points : None
2018-11-16 02:23:41 wednesday_attended : 
2018-11-16 02:23:41 wednesday_arrived : 
2018-11-16 02:23:41 thursday_points : None
2018-11-16 02:23:41 thursday_attended : 
2018-11-16 02:23:41 thursday_arrived : 
2018-11-16 02:23:41 friday_points : None
2018-11-16 02:23:41 friday_attended : 
2018-11-16 02:23:41 friday_arrived :
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. It wasn't really clear from the code I posted, but the form had most of the inputs outside the tags. IE, apparently, can't figure out that those tags belong to the form. I fixed it by placing the form tags around all of the input tags. Another solution might be to use the form attribute for input tags:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input id="something" type="text">
</form>

<button form="myform" type="submit">Submit that form over there</button>
```

But I haven't verified this will work.